# OnListItemClick с аргументом new OnItemClickListener() приводит к ошибке

Tags: java, android, listview

Не могу понять в чем причина, при попытке выполнить код ниже Eclipse выдает ошибку:

1. ```
   Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
   ```

   1. Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

Если

```
listView.**setOnItemClickListener**(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                }
```

закомментировать или изменить на

```
listView.**setOnItemClickListener**(null)
```

то ошибка пропадает, подскажите как мне подключить обработчик к ListView

p.s. выполнял add support lib, fix prodject, clean
p.s.s. target=android-15

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class CustomerWaitingListActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomerRegisterAdapter registerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerAdapter = new CustomerRegisterAdapter(this);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(registerAdapter);
        registerAdapter.loadObjects();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
            }           
        });

    }
```

Адаптер

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;

public class CustomerRegisterAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public CustomerRegisterAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("CustomerRegister");
                //query.whereEqualTo("highPri", true);
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    // Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
    @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.register_item, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

        TextView timeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reg_item_time);              
        timeText.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm", object.getCreatedAt()));

        TextView customerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reg_item_customer);      
        customerText.setText(object.getString("customer"));

        TextView serviceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reg_item_service);        
        serviceText.setText(object.getString("serviceDescription"));

        TextView idText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reg_item_objectId);
        idText.setText(object.getObjectId());

        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: target sdk version какая? Поставьте побольше

Comment: Попробуйте переместить строку 

    registerAdapter.loadObjects();

над

   ListView listView = (ListView)...;

Comment: target=android-15

Местами поменял, не помогло

Код адаптера выложил

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку

    super.getItemView(....);

И переименовать метод в `getView` вместо `getItemView`

Comment: Убрал строку
super.getItemView();

к сожалению не помогло, я предполагаю, что это наверно как-то связанно с работой ParseQueryAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря наводке [[[[@SuperCreeper](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper) поискал похожую ситуацию на parse.com и нашел решение:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
               ParseObject parseObject = customParseQueryAdapter.getItem(position);
                //do what you want with parseObject
        }
```

[[[[@SuperCreeper](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper) спасибо за помощь!